# Serial port with jSSC in linux

Tags: java, linux, jssc

I'm trying to work with serial port in java with jSSC.
My code:

```
import jssc.SerialPortList;
....
String[] ports = SerialPortList.getPortNames();
```

but it always return empty array.

```
brut@brut-Z97-D3H:~$ dmesg | grep tty
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[    0.957537] 00:05: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've faced the same issue recently, here's what I've managed to find out.

The first thing you should check is whether you have enough rights to access tty* interface.

Firstly, make sure your user is in `dialout` group. If not, execute

```
sudo adduser phil dialout
```

and then give yourself rights to read-write to the exact port.

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyS0
```

After that `SerialPortList.getPortNames()` should return `ttyS0`